# Can I use the adverb 'each' like this?

Tags: adverbs

If two boys jump and two boys jump, 'two boys each (=four boys) jump' makes sense?

Comment: can you explain more of what do you want to say ?

Comment: "Each pair jumps"?

Comment: yes it can mean each pair jumps?

Comment: Could you please explain what you want to convey through your sentence? It is quite non-understandable. If this is the only question then, what Old Brixtonian said is correct. You can even consider saying, _Each pair of boys jump._

Comment: *If two boys jump and two **other** boys jump*, you could say ***each pair** [of boys] jumped*. But we probably wouldn't use ***each*** in such contexts anyway - more likely it would be ***Both** pairs [of boys] jumped*,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Two boys each jump" means that two boys jump, not four. This phrase means the same thing as "Two boys jump", with the word "each" emphasizing that each of the two boys jumps.

This is a different use of "each" than it seems you were hoping for. If you wanted to talk about multiple groups of two, you could say something like "Each two boys jump". This is a very awkward way to phrase it, and it would be much clearer to say "Each pair of boys jumps".

Note that nothing in the word "each" indicates that there are two things being referred to—there could be three, fifty, any number.